# Django - How to avoid query the same obj

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I apologize for the extremely long message, but I'm new with this and need your knowledge and advice about *Python* and *Django*.

Basically, I am developing a small "**questions and answers**" game.I have a model with all the questions with their codes, etc.

Participants will login (they could be from 5 to 20 participants on each game), and on the screen, they will have an option that says "**ASK A QUESTION**". All participants can click the button at the same time, so how can I be sure that each user gets a *different question*?. Obviously I already thought, in placing *true / false* fields, if the question was already used, but the idea is to avoid duplication.

I come from *JAVA*, so with *synchronized methods* are not going to allow the method to be accessed at the same time, avoiding duplicate results. So is there something similar in *Python*? or is there a way to avoid that duplication?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess, you are trying to fetch all questions and send each user a unique one ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `transaction.atomic` and a field used as a flag to indicate that a question has been given. (`is_asked`?)

```
def myview(request):
    with transaction.atomic():
        valid_questions = Question.objects.select_for_update()\
            .filter(is_asked=False)
        # some code here to get a valid question
        # and return the question, then saving it as being 
        # is_asked = True before exiting the atomic block.
```

What `transaction.atomic()` guarantees is that the whole interaction is wrapped in a single transaction and `select_for_update()` locks the table until this transaction is done. That way, a concurrent click waits its turn and the database is in a consistent state before the next lookup fires.